# Display progress bar onlistitemclick()

Tags: android

Actually I know how to display progress bar using async activity using `onpreexecute()` method. But here my problem is when I click on list I am able to go other activity but it takes time to go other activity.This is because it takes data from some classes and use it to in next activity class, so till that time my process remain idle I want to show progress bar for that time of intervel on which it taking data and is idle so how to show progressbar.

If I use async task then what should be in `onpostexecute()` because all the content are position dependnt and take data according to position of list item click please tell me any solution. My code for onlistitemclick is below

```
@Override
         protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long thisID)
         {
              super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, thisID);

               Toast.makeText(this, "u clicked Id=" + keywordsearch.array_email[position] ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               galleryname  =    keywordsearch.array_galleryname[position];
               address= keywordsearch.array_address[position];
               email= keywordsearch.array_email[position];
               web= keywordsearch.array_web[position];
               phone= keywordsearch.array_phone[position];
               lati= keywordsearch.array_lati[position];
               longi= keywordsearch.array_longi[position];
               filtersearchresultparsing.galleryurl  =    keywordsearch.array_imgurl[position];
               Log.i("image url........." ,  galleryname);
   Intent i = new Intent(keywordxmlparsing.this, detailviewshowingnowTab.class);
               startActivity(i);


}}
```

Comment: I think that the delay problem is not here. Do you load image from URL in detailviewshowingnowTab?

Comment: @peceps.. yes i am loading image from server on next activity...and on next activity i use async task for loading image

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your code, you're starting a new `Activity` and then executing the remaining code in the first activity, what's the point in this? If this code refers to the first activity, you should place it before starting a new activity. If the code refers to the second activity, you should place it in this activity's `onCreate` method.

Comment: actually i am taking data from other class and save it in string type variable ,according to list position click and in next class i am using these values for display image from web service..pls refer again to my edited code

Comment: i am waiting for ur reply pls

Comment: So, does your code work well after this edit? Can you post the onCreate method of activity being started?

Comment: ya my code is working well but i just want to show progressbar when i click on list ..which class onCreate() method u want ?next class or same class?

Comment: Your delay appears because you perform too many code in the onCreate method of the activity that you're trying to start by intent, so better will be to move this code to AsyncTask accompanied with a progress dialog.